# Squish, Python, Windows application automation

Tags: python, squish

I've started using Squish to automate Windows application using Python. A few scripts are working only with `waitForObject` and a few with `waitForObjectItem`. When should I use `waitForObject` and when should I use `waitForObjectItem`?

Answer (score 1):

I often visit this: http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/

It's really helping especially when I forget something. It's just helpful.

Here it is, just copy/pate from the above site:

> **waitForObject(objectOrName)**:
>   Waits until the objectOrName object is accessible (i.e., it exists and
>   is visible and enabled). It returns a reference to the object if
>   successful or raises a (catchable) LookupError exception on failure
>
> **waitForObjectItem(objectOrName, itemIdentifier)**:
>   Waits until the objectOrName object is accessible (i.e., it exists and
>   is visible and enabled), and contains an item that is identified by
>   the itemIdentifier and that is itself accessible. This function is
>   typically used to access items inside containers such as lists,
>   tables, and trees.

Now, in other words, I understand that

**waitForObject**: its just waiting for an object that exists now and are visible, meaning that if you have a window1, on top of window2, and last one, window2 is not visible because of window1, you won't use this function;

and

**waitForObjectItem**: having in mind the first fction, object exists and is visible and enabled and this **Item** can be a cell of a table; or a children from a tree, etc.